# Batch File IF Else info

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, goto

I am attempting to get my script to GOTO Manual if the criteria below is not met . 
How ever if the get_info.bat fails and throws a error my script stops and just displays the batch file error (calling python script) . It works when the condtions are met but not on error / not met.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=" %%x in ('get_info.bat ^| find /i "agentVersion: 4"') do @set HPSAAGT=%%x
ECHO %HPSAAGT%

IF "%HPSAAGT%"=="agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0" (set AGTVERSION=45.0.31322.0) ELSE IF "%HPSAAGT%"=="agentVersion: 40.0.0.1.106" (set AGTVERSION=40.0.0.1.106) ELSE (GOTO MANUAL)
```

Comment: Works fine for me - post what the value of %HPSAAGT% is - don't leave us to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine for me... it may be a problem with your variable.  Try `echo -%HPSAAGT%-` to see if there are extra spaces in your variable.

Additionally, if you just want the version number, you should just use string manipulation, example:

```
echo %HPSAAGT:~14%
```

would result in

```
45.0.31322.0
```

Comment: There are no extra spaces: he said "It works when the condtions are met"

Comment: Correct Stephen , 

Peter = 99/100 it works when the varible equals either of these two below
HPSAAGT = agentVersion: 45.0.31322.0
HPSAAGT = agentVersion: 40.0.0.1.106

If get info or get_facility throws an error it should GOTO MANUAL which just calls the manual installer .

The Manual installer works the issue I have is the error which doesnt GOTO Label it just stops the script .

Comment: My mistake, I missed that.  @JimboMuldy the code you shared is correct, we cannot troubleshoot without seeing the rest of it.

Comment: Hm - I see no reason, why the GOTO shouldn't work. Have you verified with a "echo Yes I Jumped" right after the Label :manual ?

Comment: @JimboMuldy what do you mean by "throw an error"? Does it even make it to the if else statements?  And a sort of silly question but, the `manual` label IS in the same batch file right?

Answer (score 0):

```
if a==b (echo ab) else if b==c (echo bc) else (goto manual)
rem some more code
pause
:manual
echo Manual
```

works fine.

Is there possibly a misspelling in your Label `:manual` ?

Comment: Copied and pasted , retyped and highlighted duplicate varibles in the text editor so . every thing appears to be the same